# CSS/HTML background image not working

Tags: html, css

I have been programming for over a month now non-stop. Now I have a problem. I am doing a background image. And it does not work!

Here is the HTML code:

[Html Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKdDe.png)

And here is the CSS code:

[CSS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kjyo.png)

Comment: Please include the actual code, rather than images of your code.

Comment: Most likely your image path is wrong. Check your console for errors.

Comment: If you post the actual code here on this page (use the "<>" icon) then we can tell you what went wrong.

Comment: is your background image in the root directory?

Comment: what will we do with your HTML in image. use this before asking ur question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please make sure, your image that you are setting for background and the css file should be at same label/same place (i.e in same folder weather at root level or inside and folder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't run your code but I got my own version of your code to work as long as you have no-repeat set, and center center the background image in a div it works. Set a min-height for the container so the background always shows:

```css
.background-thing {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/400x400') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="background-thing"></div>
```